# How to find the number of misclassification entry from the Minkowski Score value?

Tags: dataset, classification

Suppose, I have a dataset with 2000 entry of 2 attributes. After passing the dataset into a classification method, it returns a `minkowski score(MS)` value.

Suppose, Cluster No = 3, Minkowski score = 0.60

I want to know that `is there any way to find the number of misclassification from the MS value.?`

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible

The MS can be written as `sqrt(N01 + N10)/sqrt(N11 + N10)` where

N11: number of points which are in same cluster in both True and Test

N10: in same cluster in True but not in Test

N01: in same cluster in Test but not in True

Given the MS and True clustering, you can get N11, but you have only one equation to solve for both N01 and N10. There is no easy relation between N10 and N01 because each miss-classification would result in changes which would be related to their cluster size.